# How do I check if a parse has failed?

Tags: string, parsing, haskell

I want to keep apply a parser to a string, and adding its output until I get to the end of the string. Unfortunately, when I parse the end of the string, it fails so I get an empty list. I want to be able to check if a parse has failed, then get the output from all the parses before that failed parse. I am trying to parse this string into a list of floats. How can I stop this from happening (i.e getting an empty list instead of my list of floats).

I have written a parser with this type:  `newtype Parser a = MkP (String -> [(String,a)])`
and its monad instance is this:

```
-- (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
instance Monad Parser where 
    return x = MkP f
        where
            f inp = [(inp,x)]
    f >>= g = MkP s 
        where
            s inp = [(rest,out) | (firstremain,firstout) <- applyParser f inp, (rest,out) <- applyParser (g firstout) firstremain]
```

Failed parses are represented by an empty list []. I have these main parsers:

```
item :: Parser Char
item = MkP f
    where
        f [] = []
        f (x:xs) = [(xs,x)]


zero :: Parser Char
zero = MkP f
    where
        f _ = []
```

I am trying to parse this string:

```
unparsedboeyield = "0.63    0.81    1.01    1.20    1.38    1.54    1.68    1.79    1.89    1.97    2.05    2.11    2.17    2.23    2.28    2.33    2.37    2.42    2.45    2.49    2.53    2.56    2.59    2.62    2.64    2.67    2.69    2.71    2.73    2.75    2.77    2.79    2.80    2.82    2.83    2.84    2.85    2.87    2.87    2.88    2.89    2.90    2.90    2.91    2.91    2.92    2.92    2.92    2.93    2.93"
```

with this parser:

```
numberParser :: Parser Float
numberParser = do
    a <- item
    b <- item
    c <- item
    d <- item
    let number = read [a,b,c,d] :: Float in return number

yieldParser :: Parser [Float]
yieldParser = do
    x <- numberParser
    helper [x] where
        helper y = do 
            a <- randomthing
            helper (y ++ [a])
        randomthing = do
            item
            item
            item
            item
            numberParser
```

I don't understand what is happening when in `helper`, what is `a` when randomthing has failed (it can't be [] then it would raise a type error as it is not a float). When I try and parse the string this happens:

applyParser yieldParser boeunparsedyield => []

The whole code is here:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Char


interpolate :: (Ord a, Fractional a) => ((a,a),(a,a)) -> a -> a
interpolate ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) x = if (x > x2) || (x < x1) then error "value out of range" else y1 + difference * gradient

    where
        gradient = (y1 -y2)/(x1 - x2)
        difference = x - x1


pvt :: Fractional a => a -> Int -> a
pvt x t = x / (m + spotrate t)^t where m = 1 :: Fractional a => a

unparsedboeyield :: String
unparsedboeyield = "0.63    0.81    1.01    1.20    1.38    1.54    1.68    1.79    1.89    1.97    2.05    2.11    2.17    2.23    2.28    2.33    2.37    2.42    2.45    2.49    2.53    2.56    2.59    2.62    2.64    2.67    2.69    2.71    2.73    2.75    2.77    2.79    2.80    2.82    2.83    2.84    2.85    2.87    2.87    2.88    2.89    2.90    2.90    2.91    2.91    2.92    2.92    2.92    2.93    2.93"
newtype Parser a = MkP (String -> [(String,a)])


applyParser :: Parser a -> String -> [(String,a)]
applyParser (MkP x) y = x y 


-- (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
instance Monad Parser where 
    return x = MkP f
        where
            f inp = [(inp,x)]
    f >>= g = MkP s 
        where
            s inp = [(rest,out) | (firstremain,firstout) <- applyParser f inp, (rest,out) <- applyParser (g firstout) firstremain]



item :: Parser Char
item = MkP f
    where
        f [] = []
        f (x:xs) = [(xs,x)]


zero :: Parser Char
zero = MkP f
    where
        f _ = []

sat :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
sat predicate = 
    item >>= \x ->
    if predicate x then return x else zero


doParser :: Parser a -> Int -> Parser ()
doParser x count = helper count
    where
        helper count = do
            if count > 0 then do
                x
                helper (count - 1)
            else return ()
numberParser :: Parser Float
numberParser = do
    a <- item
    b <- item
    c <- item
    d <- item
    let number = read [a,b,c,d] :: Float in return number

yieldParser :: Parser [Float]
yieldParser = do
    x <- numberParser
    helper [x] where
        helper y = do 
            a <- randomthing
            helper (y ++ [a])
        randomthing = do
            item
            item
            item
            item
            numberParser




spotrate :: Fractional a => Int -> a
spotrate = \t -> if (t == 1) then 5 else 2

untilParser :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser [Char]
untilParser p = helper []
    where
        helper x = do
            y <- item
            if p y then helper (x ++ [y]) else return x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
helper y = do 
    a <- randomthing
    helper (y ++ [a])
```

> what is a when randomthing has failed

`a` never gets a value when `randomthing` produces an empty list.

If you look at the definition of `>>=`, `g` is applied to `firstout` for each result in `applyParser f inp`. So if `applyParser f inp` yields zero results, `g` is applied zero times.

In the definition of helper `f` is `randomthing` and `g` is `\a -> helper (y ++ [a])`. So if `g` is never applied (which it isn't when `randomthing produces an empty list for the given input)`, `a` doesn't have a value because `a` only exists inside `g`.

> I want to be able to check if a parse has failed

You can't do that using the monadic interface. Instead you'll have to use `applyParser` yourself and then check whether it returned an empty list.